# jqchart formatting date correctly

Tags: jquery, jqchart

My line data is such that:

```
var line1 = [[2012-07-06, 4], [2012-07-05, 10], [2012-07-04, 3]]; 
var line2 = [[2012-07-06, 15], [2012-07-05, 0], [2012-07-04, 9]];
```

I am having difficulty getting the date to show in the xaxis.  While my dates are all yyyy-mm-dd, it keeps showing only years but not even the correct years.  It's showing 1991, 1992, 1993, etc.

My axes looks like:

> axes:{
>        xaxis:{
>                       type: 'dateTime',
>                       labels: { stringFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd' }
>                   }
>               }

What am I missing?

Comment: Shouldn't the dates be strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use the `Date()` data type.

See documentation here http://www.jqchart.com/samples/ChartAxes/DateTimeAxis.

Example from their site:

```
$('#jqChart').jqChart({
    title: { text: 'DateTime Axis' },
    axes: [
             {
                 type: 'dateTime',
                 location: 'bottom',
                 minimum: new Date(2011, 1, 4),
                 maximum: new Date(2011, 1, 18),
                 interval: 1,
                 intervalType: 'days'
             }
          ],
    series: [
                {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: [[new Date(2011, 1, 6), 70], [new Date(2011, 1, 8), 82],
                           [new Date(2011, 1, 10), 85], [new Date(2011, 1, 12), 70],
                           [new Date(2011, 1, 14), 65], [new Date(2011, 1, 16), 68]]
                }
            ]
});
```